# Is there a better way to set and share parent-child state other than prop handlers?

Tags: reactjs

[Demo](http://selfish-story.surge.sh/)

I am trying to set the `avatar` state on a Parent Component `<App/>` via a Child Component `<Frame/>`. It works. But I was wondering, is this the right way, or is there a better way? I am investigating all possibles way to do this.

Also, what if I have many complex parent-child hierarchies. Can I still manage it nicely this way without using Redux? My goal is to survey the patterns in the community here.

Initially, I was surprised that I am unable to access a Parent's state from the Child without prop handlers. But then I realized that React likes its state to be localized to components. I still think too many props are a pain.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Frame from './Frame';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      avatar : 'http://placehold.it/128x128',
      text: ''
    }
  }

  changeUserAvatar = (avatar) => {
    let text = `{avatar} state change triggered from Child Component: ${avatar}`;
    this.setState({
        avatar,
        text
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <p> Hello from Parent Component </p>
        <div className="Image">
          <img src={this.state.avatar}/>
        </div>
        <Frame onChangeUserAvatar={this.changeUserAvatar} consoleText={this.state.text} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

---

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Frame.css';

class Frame extends Component {

    requestNewAvatarViaId = (e) => {

        const id = e.target.value;
        if (isNaN(id) || id == '') {
            return;
        }

        fetch(`https://reqres.in/api/users/${id}`)
        .then(
            response => {
                response.json()
                .then(
                    data => {
                        this.props.onChangeUserAvatar(data.data.avatar);
                    }
                )
            }
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Frame">
                Hello from Child Component <input type="number" min="1" onChange={this.requestNewAvatarViaId}/>
                <p> {this.props.consoleText} </p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Frame;
```

Comment: This is how its recommended in the React docs too, so this is a good way to do it

Comment: I think what you have been doing is pretty straight and perfect.  If you have more children to access then you can use Redux store

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to share your parent's state with your children (if you're not using Redux) :
 - using props
 - using context

IMO, if you have a complex architecture with several nested children I'd recommend you to use the context API that React provides otherwise use props.

In this way, the code you provided is the right way to update the parent's state

Comment: What you do you mean by context

Comment: Context is a new React API here is the documentation https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html